# Changing malloc to new operator

Tags: c++, malloc, new-operator

I am changing a path planning code from C to C++. The code dynamically allocates  the states in map. I don't clearly understand the difference between `new` and `malloc`. I get an error for following snippet of code.

```
typedef struct cell
{ 
   int x,y;
   struct cell *n[5];
}cell_t;

typedef struct pq
{
   cell_t **heap;
   int len,cap;
}pq_t;

//for C version
func(pq_t *pq,50)
{
   pq->heap = malloc(sizeof(cell)*50);
   pq->len = 0;
   pq->cap = 0;
}
//for C++ version
func(pq_t *pq,50)
{
   pq->heap = (cell_t*)::operator new(sizeof(cell_t)*50);
   pq->len = 0;
   pq->cap = 0;
}
```

The error I get is :

> cannot convert ‘`cell_t`* {aka `cell*`}’ to ‘`cell_t**` {aka `cell_s**`}’ in assignment
>
> ```
> pq->heap =(cell_t*) ::operator new (sizeof(cell_t) * (50));""
> ```

What do I need to change?

Comment: Why are you calling `operator new` explicitly?

Comment: Why change it at all if it works?

Comment: @wRAR : I am calling `operator new` explicitly to allocate memory.

Comment: @SUGMAR you should read how to allocate memory in C++ then.

Comment: Why are you moving to C++ one line at a time? You'll never arrive at [`std::make_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap) that way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
pq->heap = (cell_t*)::operator new(sizeof(cell_t)*50);
```

You want this:

```
pq->heap = new cell_t[50];
```

That said, it's clear that the code you've posted is not quite your real code, so there could be some additional mistake in there.  Maybe update your question with real code that compiles.

Comment: Bearing in mind that you also need to use `delete[]` rather than plain `delete` to deallocate it.

Answer (score 4):

new takes the type or an array of types, the size is then calculated i.e.

```
cell_t* p = new cell_t // allocate one cell

cell_t* p = new cell_t[50] // allocate 50 cells.
```

However I think you would be much better off with using one of the standard containers in your program like std::vector

```
#include <vector>
..

std::vector<cell_t> myarray(50); // allocate 50 cell_t
```

then you do not need to concern yourself with freeing the memory, std::vector handles that for you.